# Kotlin: MutableLiveData HashMap of ViewModel is not observed

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to check 2 EditText fields are filled or not in real time.

So I created `ViewModel` which has `MutableLiveData<HashMap<String, Boolean>>`.

```
class PhoneFillClass : ViewModel() {
    var _phoneFillCheck = MutableLiveData<HashMap<String, Boolean>>()
    var phoneFillCheck = _phoneFillCheck.value
init {
    phoneFillCheck = hashMapOf(
        "first" to false,
        "second" to false,
    )
}

fun changePhoneFill(field: String, fill: Boolean) {
    phoneFillCheck?.set(field, fill)

   }
}
```

This hasMap has two objects in map, first and second.
And Both are initiated as `false`.

If `EditText`s text length becomes 4, I will make each first or second key's value changed to `true`.

```
 binding.phoneInput1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            //null
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(char: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            if (char?.length == 4) {
                binding.errorMessage.visibility = View.GONE
                phoneTxtCheck.changePhoneFill("first", true)
            } else {
                binding.errorMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                phoneTxtCheck.changePhoneFill("first", false)
            }
        }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        // null
    }
})
```

Like above, `phoneTxtCheck.changePhoneFill("first", true)` this line changes value of first key of MutableLiveData.

And I register this ViewModel.

```
    phoneTxtCheck._phoneFillCheck.observeForever(Observer { value ->
        Log.d("9th", "$value")
        binding.phoneAuthBtn.isEnabled = (value["first"] == true && value["second"] == true)
    })
```

So that if both of "first" and "second" 's values become true, I will enable Button.

But It doesn't work and when I Log `value` from observeForever, It prints nothing.

I'm not familiar with MutableLiveData and ViewModel in Kotlin, Please let me know which part is wrong in my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two mutable live data object can observe according to use.

> in ViewModel create two object.

```
val editText1 by lazy { MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)}
val editText2 by lazy { MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)}
```

> in activity update the value when your editText condition satisfied

```
viewModel.editText1.value = true
```

> Observe the changes in the mutableLiveData

```
viewModel.editText1.observe( this@ActivityName ){ value ->
    binding.phoneAuthBtn.isEnabled = viewModel.editText1.value && viewModel.editText2.value
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks. I'm curious why hashmap is not working even I change code by opinion of @sajidjuneja

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
init {
    phoneFillCheck = hashMapOf(
        "first" to false,
        "second" to false,
    )
}
```

to

```
init {
    _phoneFillCheck.value = hashMapOf(
        "first" to false,
        "second" to false,
    )
}
```

and observe `phoneFillCheck`.

Comment: I did this but still not working

Comment: Also change ````phoneFillCheck?.set(field, fill)```` to ````_phoneFillCheck.value!!.set(field, fill)````

Answer (score 0):

Livedata will trigger the observer method when **value inside the livedata is changed**

you can change your code into something like this

```
fun changePhoneFill(field: String, fill: Boolean) {
    phoneFillCheck?.set(field, fill)
    _phoneFillCheck.value = phoneFillCheck
   }
}
```

also, there is few of the code you provided can be improved, such as :

- use `observe` instead `observerForever`

  `observe` take additional parameter of `viewLifecycleOwner`, so livedata can avoid trigger the callback when activity/fragment no longer in active state, thus avoiding memory leak
- use `doOnTextChanged` instead of `addTextChangedListener`

  `doOnTextChanged` provide the same functionality with  `addTextChangedListener#onTextChanged` without overriding the other 2 method